# Create a shared lib using another shared lib

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a shared library "libwiston.so". I am using this to create another shared library called "libAnimation.so", which will be used by another project. Now, the second library "libAnimation.so" can't be used in test code correctly. So I doubt that the creation of the second lib "libAnimation.so" is right. The gcc command to create this lib is

```
 g++ -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libwiston.so -o libAnimation.so $(objs) -lc".
```

Has someone come across this problem?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a weird link line - you are creating `libAnimation.so`, but its internal `DT_SONAME` name is `libwiston.so`.

I don't think that what you wanted to do. Don't you want to link `libAnimation.so` against `libwiston.so` (`-lwiston`)?

```
g++ -g -shared -o libAnimation.so $(objs) -lc -lwiston
```

I think it would be easier to wrap your build in automake/autoconf and rely on libtool to get the shared library creation correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested this command, but I will use automake/autoconf to create this shared lib

Comment: @mpouse check for some libwiston stuff copypasted for libAnimation in your Makefile.am

Answer (score 0):

I'll do a humble review on the process of creating shared libraries.

Let's begin by creating *libwiston.so*. First we implement the function we would like to export and then define it on a header so other programs knows how to call it.

```
/* file libwiston.cpp
 * Implementation of hello_wiston(), called by libAnimation.so
 */
#include "libwiston.h"

#include <iostream>

int hello_wiston(std::string& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
/* file libwiston.h
 * Exports hello_wiston() as a C symbol.
 */
#include <string>

extern "C" {
int hello_wiston(std::string& msg);
};
```

This code can be compiled with: `g++ libwiston.cpp -o libwiston.so -shared`

Now we implement the second shared library, named *libAnimation.so* that calls the function exported by the first library.

```
/* file libAnimation.cpp
 * Implementation of call_wiston(). 
 * This function is a simple wrapper around hello_wiston().
 */
#include "libAnimation.h"
#include "libwiston.h"

#include <iostream>

int call_wiston(std::string& param)
{
    hello_wiston(param);

    return 0;
}
```

and header:

```
/* file libAnimation.h
 * Exports call_wiston() as a C symbol.
 */
#include <string>

extern "C" {
int call_wiston(std::string& param);
};
```

Compile it with: `g++ libAnimation.cpp -o libAnimation.so -shared -L. -lwiston`

Finally, we create a small application to test libAnimation.

```
/* file demo.cpp
 * Implementation of the test application.
 */
#include "libAnimation.h"
int main()
{
    std::string msg = "hello stackoverflow!";
    call_wiston(msg);
}
```

And compile it with: `g++ demo.cpp -o demo -L. -lAnimation`

There's an interesting tool named **nm** that you can use to list the symbols exported by your shared library. Using these examples, you could execute the following commands to check for the symbols:

```
nm libAnimation.so | grep call_wiston
```

outputs:

```
00000634 t _GLOBAL__I_call_wiston
000005dc T call_wiston
```

and also:

```
nm libwiston.so | grep hello_wiston
```

outputs:

```
0000076c t _GLOBAL__I_hello_wiston
000006fc T hello_wiston
```

Comment: I think the linking of the application will fail with undefined reference to `hello_wiston` if you don't link it to `libwiston.so`. It would work though if you had `libwiston.a`.

Comment: @Dmitry The linking will succeed and the demo will work! The only binary that needs to be linked with libwiston.so is libAnimation and that's being done.

Comment: What system you've tested it on? On debian gcc-4.4.5, ld-2.20.1 it gives `./libAnimation.so: undefined reference to `hello_wiston'` like I mentioned.

Comment: @Dmitry Ubuntu 10.04 and gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3